# System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException occured

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, interop

I wrote a very simple code that reads and writes from a card. I got an error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException' occured in
>   ReadandWrite.exe
>
> Additional information: PInvoke restriction: can not return variants.

Code Snippet:

```
Console.WriteLine("Address = 0x3c3, Value = 0x", MX4.r_1byte(963).ToString)
```

I am trying to understand the error and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're forgetting to declare an Interop Type for one or more of your Public methods/properties. See [this MSDN thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3bd0489b-49e9-49f4-8e66-2b3d5cf15bea/pinvoke-restriction-cannot-return-variants).

Comment: Actually this might be it. I will try it, and run it and get back to you. Thank you for your help.

Comment: there were few other errors. After I implemented your correction and other obvious fixes, It works! Thank you. Thank you. Thank you.